# SendKeys.SendWait() doesn't work consistently on all computers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sendkeys

I am using SendKeys.SendWait() to copy and paste text back and forth between windows. I've written a copy-paste method which uses the `FindWindow` and `SetForegroundWindow` methods from `"User32.dll"`

Most of the time on my device, the method works perfectly. However, it is very inconsistent when running on different devices. All devices are using the same operating system and have about the same applications open.

Sometimes, the method pastes the wrong text (from a previous copy) and sometimes the method just doesn't work at all.

I've made sure to be using the new `SendKeys.SendWait()` implementation as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait?view=netframework-4.7.2).

I've also tried putting in a sleep function in between the copy and paste functions. This doesn't seem to affect the output, other than making it slower. Even with the sleep, the program copies and pastes inconsistently.

```
public static bool CopyPaste(string startWindow, string endWindow, int delay = 0)
{
    int startWindowID = FindWindow(null, startWindow);
    int endWindowID = FindWindow(null, endWindow);

    SetForegroundWindow(startWindowID);

    SendKeys.SendWait("^{a}");
    SendKeys.SendWait("^{c}");

    Thread.Sleep(delay);

    SetForegroundWindow(endWindowID);

    SendKeys.SendWait("^{a}");
    SendKeys.SendWait("^{v}");
}
```

I know that copying and pasting to and from other windows is finicky and not a great idea, but I have no other choice.

**Is using `SendKeys.SendWait()` the correct way to go about this? Is there a different, more reliable way to do it? What can I do to improve its reliability across platforms?**

Edit:
While the Clipboard class does transfer the text correctly, it seems to be even less reliable. It often throws an error saying that the "Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed."

Comment: from arbitrary window to another arbitrary window? or special windows like MS Word?

Comment: @kennyzx One of the windows is just an arbitrary window (I usually test in wordpad). The other window is the program form itself. I've been using `FindWindow` to find the windows handles based on their names. The naming of the windows is consistent on all devices.

Comment: For the program itself, consider using [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard?view=netframework-4.7.2) class, which provides direct access to the system clipboard, use the `Clipboard.GetText/SetText` method to replace Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V, and then you only need to use `SendKeys` to manipulate the arbitrary window.

Comment: That being said, `SendKeys` is really really a loose approach, it cannot guarantee a successful operation every time, its outcome is affected by many factors. I would not go this approach unless the program is 'just for fun'.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll take another look at it. I tried using the clipboard class originally and ran into several issues which is why I switched to `SendKeys.SendWait()`

Comment: @kennyzx Using the Clipboard class actually made things worse. The copying and pasting is less reliable. While it still works sometimes, it often throws a Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed error.